# How to connect Ultrium 460 tape drive? (Ultra320 SCSI)

Tags: scsi, tape, pci-x, hostadapter

I have the opportunity to get, for nothing, an Ultrium 460 tape drive, and LOTS of tapes, which would give me enormous amounts of storage space to frivolously use on nothing at all. The problem is that it's a dual channel SCSI interface device that accepts at 68-pin cable (in case the jargon's wrong, it has two Ultra320 wide SCSI connectors, one for the input, one for the output), and I have no server with an integrated SCSI controller to manage it. So I'm looking for a controller card to go into one of my current computers, none of which have server-grade motherboards, and all lack a PCI-X slot.

The issue is that of all the cards I'm finding, they mostly have what I believe is LVD/SE. I don't know if you can convert between LVD/SE inputs and 68-pin Ultra320 wide. The card that I have access to is PCI-X so it's no use, but it has this 68-pin connector mounted on top of the card (as most of the cards I'm finding online do as well), implying that this tape drive may have been mounted in a disk management system we have, but it has only one connector, and I was under the impression that SCSI was almost always a separate cable for input/output-type system. So if I bought one of these that fit into my computer, could I swap the cables for the tape drive? As in, when I wanted to write to the tape drive, would I just connect the input cable of the tape drive to the internal connector, and then when I wanted to read from a tape do the reverse?

My question is, how would I connect this tape drive to my PCI-X-lacking computers? I'm finding PCIe cards, but they are a painful $180+, which I hope to avoid. This card doesn't have to write at 480Mbits/s, it just needs to be able to write faster than 2400baud.

Comment: SCSI is chainable, not 1 cable for in/out

Comment: Please don't vote to close, this is a obscure piece of hardware. See http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2324/in-defense-of-obscure-niche-hardware-recommendation-questions